# How can I log in as any given user with Drush?

Tags: drush

How do you login to a Drupal site if you do not have the password of the admin user or user 1 but still have access to the command line? Can I use Drush to log in to the Drupal site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log in to any Drupal site if you have access to the command line and Drush, knowing either the username

```
$ drush uli username --no-browser
```

OR the user ID.

```
$ drush uli --uid 123 --no-browser
```

This will return you an URL that you can copy paste into your browser address bar and login as that user. You can leave out the `--no-browser` option when you want the command to directly launch the browser.

Comment: To update the domain, use `--uri` like this: `drush uli username --uri=http://example.com`.